# UVM end-of-test mechanism

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

```
task mabu_scoreboard::main_phase(uvm_phase phase);
forever begin
    # 1ns;
    if(extip_rd_req_cnt - extip_rd_rsp_cnt >= `MABU_READ_OST_NUM) begin
        hit_rd_max_outstanding = 1;
        `uvm_info(get_type_name(),"reach read outstanding threshold!",UVM_NONE);
    end else begin
        hit_rd_max_outstanding = 0;
    end

    if(extip_wr_req_cnt - extip_wr_rsp_cnt >= `MABU_WRITE_OST_NUM) begin
        hit_wr_max_outstanding = 1;
        `uvm_info(get_type_name(),"reach write outstanding threshold!",UVM_NONE);
    end else begin
        hit_wr_max_outstanding = 0;
    end
end  endtask
```

The `forever` loop is executed in a time-consuming phase (`main_phase`).  The test can get terminated correctly because the `main_phase` does not raise an objection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One starting a time-consuming UVM phase, there must be at least one objection raised to prevent that phase from being terminated. Terminating a phase means the process of all `uvm_component`s executing that phase will be killed.

In your scoreboard example, we would have to assume some other component raises an objection to the `main_phase`, otherwise the `forever` loop would never complete its first iteration. It's better to use the `run_phase` for a process that needs to execute for the entire test.

Having any kind of delay in your UVM testbench except for generation of the clock is a bad practice. A UVM testbench is supposed to be transaction based and the only delays should be in generating your clocks. A `forever` loop with a 1ns polling delay is especially bad for performance. A much better approach is to blocking waiting for an event.

Comment: thanks dave,  "A forever loop with a 1ns polling delay is especially bad for performance." what if the clock is running at 1ns, does it have any different in terms of performance?

Comment: Probably not as much. With polling it all a question of relative activity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct.  Since the `main_phase` in your scoreboard does not call `raise_objection`, the scoreboard will not prevent the test from ending.

Most of your testbench components will not raise objections.  It is common for your test (the class extended from `uvm_test`) to raise objections in its time-consuming phase.